# MySQL Jdbc convert string to date

Tags: mysql, jdbc

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
// date here is a string of format yyyy-MM-dd
 java.util.Date date_1 = df.parse(date) ;
java.sql.Date sqldate = new java.sql.Date(date_1.getTime());
sql = "select * from fgs_stock_report where Report_date = ? ";

PreparedStatement two = con.prepareStatement(sql);
two.setDate(1,sqldate);ResultSet rs ;
rs = two.executeQuery(sql) ;
```

Here I get a Java Sql Exception asking for the right syntax near? . I am a beginner and I searched a lot for a solution but couldnt find. Please help me.

Comment: Post the complete stack trace of the exception, so that we can know what the problem is.

Comment: does your table contains date in this foramt 2014-06-29

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I see the problem, you are using a [`Statement.executeQuery(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeQuery%28java.lang.String%29) but you want [`PreparedStatement.executeQuery()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeQuery%28%29) - that is.

```
PreparedStatement two = con.prepareStatement(sql); // <-- Prepare a Statement.
two.setDate(1,sqldate);                            // <-- bind the parameter.
ResultSet rs ;
rs = two.executeQuery(sql) ;                       // <-- throw it away and use raw sql
```

What you want is,

```
 ResultSet rs = two.executeQuery();                // <-- I'd use one line
```